# Google charts — how to prevent selection of certain points?

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to have a Google Chart on which some data points are selectable whilst others aren't? I presume this would be possible with a custom event handler, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make a 'select' handler that selects the point (using `setSelection()`) if the point is in a certain set (using `getSelection()`), but that's incredibly basic. Could you please expand on what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Literally, all I want to do is prevent all but a subset of points from being selectable.

Comment: Then what I briefly explained above should work. You let any point be clicked on, you just disable the selected behavior (`setSelection()`) for points you don't want to be selectable. So you can click on some points, but it won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: If you get stuck, just let me know. I can probably create an example when I get a few minutes.